# Words like "defenestrate" for throwing things from a moving car, and from a rooftop

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, vocabulary

When someone throws something or someone out of a window, we have a word for it: **Defenestrate**

The meaning of defenestrate given by Oxford [Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/defenestration):

> *formal* or ,*humorous* The action of throwing someone out of a window:
>
> *'death by defenestration has a venerable history'*

I am looking for two words similar to it:

1) - To throw someone/something **out of a moving car.**
2) - To throw someone/something **from a rooftop.**

I could not find any.

---

PS - I asked this question on [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/71843), but they say that it is a [Word Golf](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2718/i-dont-think-ell-should-be-word-golf) and so I am asking it here.

Comment: Umm, perhaps you have us mixed up with the Word Golf site, which does not in fact exist.

Comment: to pass the buck, why not try puzzles.SE

Comment: @Mitch so there are no words for that? Thanks :)

Comment: @Usernew There may very well be words for that, but if it's not good for ELL it is most likely not good for ELU either. Also, there are most likely no good words for those.

Comment: Well, I had to ask here to know about that. Thanks! I will use those phrases whenever I need them in my reports. Thank you!

Comment: @usernew Reports? What sort of work do you do where you commonly write such reports?

Comment: @Mitch It's actually a college project(about crimes) but I won't get into the details here. So in the report a girl was dumped from a moving car. Nevermind.

Comment: On ELL, the processes of word-formation in English should be part of the agenda. Assuming the request is frivolous should not be part of the agenda. Even supposing the request is frivolous, the opportunity to teach the learner something about English word-formation would better not be passed up. Should we punt questions like this back at ELL? I don't mean to start the 30 Years War.

Comment: @JEL: questions about word-formation in the abstract seem fine to me; questions requesting applied word-formation skills don't.

Comment: @sumelic, the answer for the OP would be "no", on either site, or simply a lack of answer. Unless you can think of the words? My objection is to having the question punted over here on the basis of it being "word golf", which it was not: it was a straightforward, well-formed request for two words which don't happen to exist in English. It was a reasonable request, as the mention of the model suggests.

Comment: Well, I agree with you about that, actually.

Comment: @JEL Thanks for your support. :) And if I knew that those words didn't exist, I would not have asked this question in the first place.

Comment: @sumelic you too :)

Comment: I still don't know the words didn't exist. All I know is that *I didn't know them*. True, I used an advanced thesaurus to search for them, and didn't find them. They exist now, howsomever flawed or partial they may be in all their wordly glory. The question was good, and I thank you for asking it.

Comment: @JEL And I thank you for taking your time and the efforts you put in :))

Comment: I think defenestration  is mainly a special historical term referring to the defenestration of Prague. And I wouldn't use such academic terms for the act of throwing something out of a moving car.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could coin a couple on the model of defenestrate (a verbal back-formation from defenestration).

### Coinages Based on Modern French

Maybe abvoiturate, although it doesn't convey the 'moving' concept, so

> a traveling abvoituration.

Then for rooftop, a tougher nut to crack, perhaps

> detoitate.

**Note and disclaimer on the French-based coinages**: I don't speak or read French, so the choice of terms for the base coins may be inappropriate, although I selected those to the best of my ability by analyzing a variety of possibilities. My confidence in 'detoitate' is high for the simple reason that I only found one translation from English 'rooftop' to French: *toit*. My confidence in 'abvoiturate' (and so 'abvoituration') is only slightly compromised by my having found these possible translations of 'car' into French: *autocar, car, tram, voiture, wagon*. Of those, however, only *voiture* covered a satisfying range of meanings when translated back into English. Those meanings included "car", "carriage", "coach", "motorcar", and "vehicle".

However, as a comment on the initial version of this answer brought to light, using French words for the base coin was premised on my misreading of the etymology of 'defenestration'. For this reason, the French-based coinages are not (as I may appear to claim) strictly on the model of 'defenestrate', which derives from Latin *fenestra*, meaning "window".

French-based coinages are workable, but the heyday of French adoptions in English is long past. Much more common today are coinages based on Latin or ancient Greek whenever a word is wanted in English and not ready to hand from another modern language.

### Coinages Based on Latin

For an ejection from a vehicle, the verb,

> abvehiculate

could be used. The substantive form would be (for a moving vehicle),

> a traveling abvehiculation.

For tossing off a rooftop, a slight correction of an offering from a comment on the initial version of this answer may be good:

> detectate.

**Note on the Latin Coinages**: My confidence in these coinages is fairly high. I did complete post-graduate study of Latin, enough to read and write the language with what was considered 'proficiency' at the time, although admittedly 30-some years have intervened between those studies and today. During those intervening years such proficiency as I attained has diminished, rather than increased.

The first, 'abvehiculate' (and so 'abvehiculation') derives from *vehiculum*, meaning "a vehicle, conveyance". This word may be applied generally, that is, not only to automobiles, but to any type of vehicle, including watercraft.

The second, 'detectate', derives from *tectum*, meaning "roof". *Tectum*, in turn, is a substantive formed from the past participle of *tego*, meaning "to cover, conceal". Hence also the existing English word 'detect', meaning "to uncover, reveal".

**Note about the prefixes and suffixes**:

The prefix 'ab-' is used in the sense of "off, away, from". The prefix 'de-' is used in the sense of "down from".

The use of the suffix '-ate' is complicated. A brief excerpt from the OED may suffice to explain the formative use:

> ... it became the recognized method of englishing a Latin verb, to take the ppl. stem of the Latin as the present stem of the English; so that English verbs were now formed on Latin pa. pples. by mere analogy, and without the intervention of a participial adjective.

["-ate, suffix3". OED Online. September 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/12404?rskey=MBq95g&result=5&isAdvanced=false (accessed October 31, 2015).]

The excerpt, of course, considerably oversimplifies a long, convoluted story about the use of '-ate' to english Latin and French words.

Comment: *defenestrate* comes from Latin, not French. So shouldn't it be *detectumate*?

Comment: I downvoted, because I don't think neologisms are on-topic/appropriate for the site. (Actually, it's also partly for a purely subjective reason: I don't like the sound of your neologisms. That is probably a bad reason; I'm sorry for that, but normally this shouldn't even be an issue.)

Comment: If neologisms aren't appropriate to this site, then the name _English Language and Usage_ is inappropriate.

Comment: I upvoted because I love the sound of "abvehiculation."  So everything balances out in the end. ;-)